# How to remove everything but video and stereo audio stream from video with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264

I'm trying to get a clean h264 video from a mkv file.With clean I mean that it has only a video stream plus stereo sound.
The inputfile can have multiple channels and subtitles and other unknown stuff, which I don't need.
I'm using ffmpeg with this command:

```
 ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -ac 2 -vf scale=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:480 -c:v libx264 "output.mp4"
```

This should give me a 480p video with stereo sound,which I require.
I tried multiple -map or dispositions commands with ffmpeg to remove the subtitles whithout any success.

How can I remove everything but video and stereo stream with ffmpeg and get a 480p stereo sound video?

Edit:
Output of ffmpeg - "input.mkv" -i "output.mp4" :

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -i "output.mp4"
ffmpeg version N-91972-gbd10c1e9a8 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developer

  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20180813
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconf
g --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-li
freetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-am
wb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy -
enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-
ibwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 -
enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --e
able-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --e
able-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --
nable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --ena
le-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 19.101 / 56. 19.101
  libavcodec     58. 30.100 / 58. 30.100
  libavformat    58. 18.101 / 58. 18.101
  libavdevice    58.  4.103 / 58.  4.103
  libavfilter     7. 32.100 /  7. 32.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
[hevc @ 00000000004a5940] Invalid default display window
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input.mkv':
  Metadata:
    title           : Elysium (2013)
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.3 + libmatroska v1.4.4
    creation_time   : 2016-01-05T22:30:41.000000Z
  Duration: 00:01:02.73, start: 0.166000, bitrate: 53638 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 62.896000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:00:00.000
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv), 3840x1606, SAR 1:
 DAR 1920:803, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Elysium (2013) - Release for ULTRAHDCLUB
      BPS             : 51036975
      BPS-eng         : 51036975
      DURATION        : 00:01:02.604000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:01:02.604000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 1501
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 1501
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 399389852
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 399389852
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v8.7.0 ('All of the above') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v8.7.0 ('All of the above') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-01-05 22:30:41
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-01-05 22:30:41
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: dts (DTS-HD MA), 48000 Hz, 7.1, s16p (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : DTS-HD MA 7.1 - Blu-ray CEE
      BPS             : 2706639
      BPS-eng         : 2706639
      DURATION        : 00:01:02.561000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:01:02.561000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 5865
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 5865
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 21166260
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 21166260
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v8.7.0 ('All of the above') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v8.7.0 ('All of the above') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-01-05 22:30:41
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-01-05 22:30:41
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : Elysium (2013)
    encoder         : Lavf58.18.101
  Duration: 00:01:02.73, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1671 kb/s
    Chapter #1:0: start 0.000000, end 62.730000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:00:00.000
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (High 10) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p10le, 1
46x480 [SAR 2030:2027 DAR 38773:16216], 1543 kb/s, SAR 15563:15540 DAR 1920:803
 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fl
p, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #1:2(eng): Data: bin_data (text / 0x74786574), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
At least one output file must be specified
```

Answer (score 1):

I could figure it out:
-map_metadata -1
did the trick.Despite the video is still not working with JavaFX Media Player

Edit:
With

```
-profile:v high -level:v 4.0  -pix_fmt yuv420p
```

I finally get a JavaFX Media Player compatible video file :)

Answer (score 1):

To remove subtitle, use `-map -0:s` option (note the "-0" minus in front of :s), like this:

```
-map 0:v -map 0:a -map -0:s
```

in front of your video&audio encoding options.

Example, to transcode MKV to MP4 with only first video and 1st audio:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "input.mkv"  -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0  -map -0:s  -c copy "output.mp4"
```

If you want to encode all video and audio streams streams without subtitle:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "input.mkv"  -map 0:v -map 0:a  -map -0:s  -c copy "output.mp4"
```

Comment: Does it work, anyway, I come here to get rid of font attachments .

Comment: Same problem here, I am converting embedded ASS to SRT, but can't figure out how to strip TTF.

Comment: And it seems that the correct answer is `-map -0:t`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -sn -dn -vf scale=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:480 -c:v libx264 -ac 2 "output.mp4"
```

`-sn` disables subtitle selection.

Comment: Already tried.VLC player still shows subtitles in codec informations.Quicktime Player and JavaFX Mediaplayer(which I need) can't even play the video.I think it must be because of this further streams.

Comment: Post the output of `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i output.mp4`

Comment: i think "Stream #1:2(eng): Data: bin_data (text / 0x74786574), 0 kb/s" might be the problem. how to remove that? in VLC it is Stream 2 codec:tx3g language english,type subtitle. I want to remove  this and possible everything which can occur in any video but the video and audio stream (which must be converted to stereo)